# How to map to multiple values in a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas df`:

```
Name
Jack
Alex
Jackie
Susan
```

i also have the following dict:

```
d = {'Jack':['Male','22'],'Alex':['Male','26'],'Jackie':['Female','28'],'Susan':['Female','30']}
```

I would like to add in two colums for `Gender` and `Age` so that my `df` returns:

```
Name      Gender    Age
Jack      Male       22
Alex      Male       26
Jackie    Female     28
Susan     Female     30
```

I have tried:

```
df['Gender'] = df.Name.map(d[0])
df['Age'] = df.Name.map(d[1])
```

but no such luck. Any ideas or help would be muhc appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions working well also if no match in dictionary like:

```
d = {'Alex':['Male','26'],'Jackie':['Female','28'],'Susan':['Female','30']}


print (df)
     Name  Gender  Age
0    Alex    Male   26
1    Jack     NaN  NaN
2  Jackie  Female   28
3   Susan  Female   30
```

---

Use [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) from your dictionary and add to column `Name` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), advantage is if more columns in input data all working same way:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=['Gender','Age']), on='Name')
print (df)
     Name  Gender Age
0    Jack    Male  22
1    Alex    Male  26
2  Jackie  Female  28
3   Susan  Female  30
```

Your solution should working if create 2 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {k:v[0] for k,v in d.items()}
d2 = {k:v[1] for k,v in d.items()}

df['Gender'] = df.Name.map(d1)
df['Age'] = df.Name.map(d2)
print (df)
     Name  Gender Age
0    Jack    Male  22
1    Alex    Male  26
2  Jackie  Female  28
3   Susan  Female  30
```

Comment: Thanks! I created `d1` and `d2` and worked great - thanks very much!

Comment: @SOK - OK, super, so always matching keys from dictioanry and values in column `Name` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
df['Gender'] = df.Name.map(lambda x: d[x][0])
df['Age'] = df.Name.map(lambda x: d[x][1])
```

Comment: Thanks very much! this worked and I ended up using the below solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor with [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat with `df`:

```
In [2696]: df = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(df.Name.map(d).tolist(), columns=['Gender', 'Age'])], axis=1)

In [2695]: df
Out[2696]: 
     Name  Gender Age
0    Jack    Male  22
1    Alex    Male  26
2  Jackie  Female  28
3   Susan  Female  30
```

Answer (score 1):

Take all the values of the dictionary

```
d = {'Jack':['Male','22'],'Alex':['Male','26'],'Jackie':['Female','28'],'Susan':['Female','30']}

value_list = list(d.values())
df = pd.DataFrame(value_list, columns =['Gender', 'Age'])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up going for the first with the answer I selected because it worked seamless with my full dataframe instead of creating a new `df` as you have in your instance